# Adding will-change: transform to css causes images to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

I have been running into some weird issues with will-change: transform while I add this property to the img and div tags. Basically, I have a div as a container that contains an img element as its child and I am scrolling through these images in webkit. Adding will-change-tranform greatly improves the scrolling performance, but as you scroll you intermittently see images disappear(or hidden). Any answers to fix this problem would be great as I have exhausted most of the solutions I have tried from online resources.

I am attaching the code snippet for the CSS:

".cell" and ".pagNum" are class name attributes for the div. 
".pageNum" is a page number div on top of the img div(.cell). ".cell" div contains the img element.

```
img {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    will-change: transform;        
}

.cell {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    will-change: transform;        
}

.pageNum {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 273px;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 36px;
    min-width: 36px;        
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);
    color: white;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000000;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -32px;  
    will-change: transform;    

}
```

Comment: What code is changing the opacity?  Could you add it to your question?  My guess would be that that's where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Thank you for your response Joe. I do not having any code that is changing the opacity. I ended up adding to will-change even though I think it is not required, the other interesting thing that I observed is that setting the "will-change" back to "auto" in my JS code after like a touch end brings back the disappeared images.